# Artifactory Cloud - How to copy an artifact without messing up the repo path in the module

Tags: artifactory

My build pipeline is uploading a multi-module Maven project to an Artifactory repository `repo1`. At the very end of the pipeline (and for certain conditions), there is a step that will copy one single artifact from `repo1` to `repo2`. I'm using the REST API: `$(ARTIFACTORY_URL)/api/copy/repo1/org/sonarsource/sonarlint/eclipse/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site/{version}/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-{version}.zip?to=/repo2/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-latest.zip&suppressLayouts=1`
This works fine, but then I noticed that when looking at the build's published modules in the build details, in front of the artifact, the repo path is now pointing to `repo2/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-latest.zip`. When browsing the repo1 tree, I can see that `org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-{version}.zip` is still there.

Then I tried to promote the build, but this fails. The zip is not promoted to the final repository. I found this in logs:

```
2020-06-12 07:56:10,266 [http-nio-8082-exec-3579] [WARN ] (o.a.a.l.t.PathTranslationHelper:68) - Unable to translate path 'org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-latest.zip': does not represent a valid module path within the source.
2020-06-12 07:56:10,895 [http-nio-8082-exec-3579] [INFO ] (o.a.b.BuildPromotionHelper:214) - Skipping promotion status update: item promotion was completed with errors and warnings.
```

Question: shouldn't the copy operation preserve the repo path of the copied artifact? Why pointing to the new copy? Or at least, shouldn't the promote operation be smart enough to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of JFrog support, we managed to get rid of this issue. When using the promote REST API, we had to specify the `sourceRepo` parameter .

Long story:
As you can see based on this [KB](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-does-build-promotion-work/) article , once a Build Promotion is triggered, Artifactory will first search for a list of artifacts it should promote. It will search based on the SHA1 values from the Build-info JSON, and the build.name & build.number properties.
Since copied artifacts have the same SHA1 (they are basically symlink), the promote will randomly take the artifact from any of the two repos where the copy exists. Specifying the `sourceRepo` parameter to the build promotion step will force it to only consider this repo, and in my case that fixed the issue.